# Jquery : autoNumeric.js Remove Formatting Number at submit

Tags: jquery, autonumeric.js

I use this [autoNumeric.js](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) plugin to formatting number at typing in textfield. Everything is fine , i can see the number is formatted at i typing. But the problem is, every i submit form , the number still formatted.

How to remove formatted number at submit form ?

#### Source Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#meteranFormat").autoNumeric("init", {
    unformatOnSubmit: true,
  });
});
```

[image]

*note , i dont know if this plugin deprecated or not.

Comment: Use two fields. One which is formatted for the UI and one which is a plain float which you send to the server.

Comment: Also note that `unformatOnSubmit` should work if: 1) you're using a `type="submit"` button in the form and 2) if you're using the most up to date version of the library. See this github issue for more details: https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/issues/442

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the AutoNumeric version you are using is deprecated for about 6 years.
It would be better to use the [newer version](https://docs.autonumeric.org/) described on docs.autonumeric.org.

With that version, you do not need the jQuery dependency anymore, and to remove the format while submitting the form, you can use `formSubmitNumericString()` (see all the form-related [functions](https://docs.autonumeric.org/Documentation/instantiated%20methods/#form-functions)).